# Can't resolve error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in swift XCODE

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I have the common error - "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". Although I can't resolve this. I have researched more about this error, I found stuff like: This error only happens when you are calling on an outlet that doesn't exist. I've looked back into my code looking for some button, label, image or anything that I do not want, I just can't find any trace of the bug! If anyone can spot a bug or anything, that would be great. Thanks!

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Useful Variables
var cashCount:Int = 0
var cashIncome:Int = 1

//The cash displaying Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var errorDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cashDisplayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cashIncomeDisplayer: UILabel!

//The other outlets

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//When the cash is clicked call this func

@IBAction func CashClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    cashCount += cashIncome
    cashDisplayLabel.text = "Cash: $\(cashCount)"
}

//The store functions
@IBAction func BuyFoodFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 10 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 10
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}

@IBAction func BuySubFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 20 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 20
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}

@IBAction func BuyCarFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 800 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 800
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}

@IBAction func BuyRVFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 1000 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 1000
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}

@IBAction func BuyLapTopFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 900 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 900
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}

@IBAction func BuyPhoneFUNC(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 700 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 700
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}
@IBAction func UpgradeCashINCOME(_ sender: Any) {
    if cashCount >= 10 {
        errorDisplay.text = "Success!"
        cashCount -= 10
        cashIncome += 1
        cashIncomeDisplayer.text = "Income: $\(cashIncome)"
    } else {
        errorDisplay.text = "Sorry, Not Enough Funds!"
    }
}
}
```

Here is a screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UUSM.jpg

Comment: Are you positive the outlets are connected in storyboard?

Comment: I'm pretty sure.. I just deleted and reconnected all the outlets I have. Although I have 2 non-connected labels. I don't need to connect those do I? They are just titles. They serve no purpose for my code.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint and post the exception reason. It's either *Unexpected found `nil`...* or *... is not key-value compliant ...* and please conform to the naming convention that function / method names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by that. Im a complete noob with XCode

Comment: Is `ViewController` being created automatically from a storyboard or are you loading it explicitly in code?

Comment: Press ⌘8, click on the `+` sign bottom left and add *Exception Breakpoint*

Comment: Also...what action causes the crash?

Comment: @PhillipMills when I click the run button, my app will open on simulater - but it wont show any content.. Its just a blank screen

Comment: Here is a screenshot 

https://imgur.com/a/Cvh0I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up assistant editor (2 circles thing on top right). Open the storyboard on the left screen and the code for the view controller that is causing the error on the right side. Make sure all the dots are bubbled in (dots appear next to where you connect your outlets) on the code side of your screen. If it isn't filled in, drag the bubble to the correct outlet [image]

Also, if you changed the name of an outlet, you will have something like the image below. Press the x to delete that connection and drag the circle to the right of it and reconnect it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me a ton!! :D

Comment: Yup, outlets can cause issues sometimes and you never seem to think to look for them.