# Swift SIGABRT Error? But I resolved it?

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

I have yet another error, its the common swift error

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

I know how to fix this error. Here is my recent question.
[Can't resolve error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in swift XCODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289247/cant-resolve-error-thread-1-signal-sigabrt-in-swift-xcode/48312100?noredirect=1#comment83690162_48312100)

But now I am making a new project, and I got this error! So I tried to fix it, I thought I got it - but I didn't.. I have checked all my outlets and everything, But there is no trace of where this is coming from...

Here is my code:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
//Variables
var tempature:Int = 50
var battery:Int = 100
var monsterCount:Int = 0

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var BatteryLevel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TempDisplay: UILabel!

//The spy camera
@IBOutlet weak var monsterImageDisplay: UIImageView?

//The background image
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageShow: UIImageView!

//Functions
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    monsterImageDisplay?.isHidden = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//The interval to keep things going
var helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("spawnMonstor")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func spawnMonstor() {
    monsterImageDisplay?.isHidden = false
    monsterCount += 1
    if monsterCount >= 3 {
        let randomNumberBackgroundImage = arc4random_uniform(10)
        if randomNumberBackgroundImage >= 5 {
            backgroundImageShow.image = UIImage(named: "main-room-jumpTop")
        } else if randomNumberBackgroundImage <= 5 {
            backgroundImageShow.image = UIImage(named: "main-room-jumpBottom")
        }
    } else if monsterCount >= 5 {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "GAME OVER", message: "Sorry! You died...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay..", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


//The shock rooms button

@IBAction func ShockRooms(_ sender: Any) { monsterImageDisplay?.isHidden = true
}

}
```

Comment: Update this question with the complete and exact error and point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that your UIImage names are the **EXACT** same names as the ones in your xcassets folder.
2. Instead of using the `helloWorldTimer`, write this at the top of your class, underneath your outlets:

`var helloWorldTimer = Timer()`

And then inside of your `viewDidLoad`, add:

```
helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("spawnMonstor")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps so much!