# Issue with solving a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I seem to be missing something! I keep getting a

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error in the delegate when

I try to run an app that I am working on. It gets to the launch screen and crashes but I just can't seem to find the issue - there is only one segue as yet and it is connected.

It is probably something really obvious but would appreciate any help!

Below is the code for the view controller that contains the segue where I believe the problem lies.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pwField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signup", sender: sender)
    }


    @IBAction func liPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        guard emailField.text != "", pwField.text != "" else {return}

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: pwField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }


            if user != nil {
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "usersVC")

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }






        })


    }


}
```

Comment: Any error message in console when it crashes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48312100/6137562 Check that out. It might be the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't resolve error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in swift XCODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289247/cant-resolve-error-thread-1-signal-sigabrt-in-swift-xcode)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you get the identifiers right (this always gets me). Otherwise, I recommend using breakpoints to isolate the cause of failure.

If the app really crashes during launch, that's a bit of a mystery to me, since you aren't executing any code of your own yet.